# Chrome on mac adding www before subdomain

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have recently hosted my site which intends to use wildcard subdomains in its general use. A user would go to account.website.com to access their part of the site. The site is a rails app hosted on heroku and domain is through 123-reg. DNS is set up as per heroku - * , cname , wildcard.app.heroku...

At first i thought 123-reg couldnt handle wildcard routing and i would have to change dns provider as whenever i go to account.website.com it will send me to www.account.website.com which is extremely irritating, but then i found that this does not happen on my windows machine, only on my dev machine (macbook pro). In both cases i am using Chrome. Firefox works as desired, only chrome is messing up.

Any insight into why this is happening would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously i immediately solve it after asking and look like a fool - Apparently the cache remembers the redirect from when i assume i hadnt yet set up dns correctly. If you get the same problem, clear browser cache